# Git log show parent of merged branch

Tags: git, logging

I have my master branch and do this:

```
git checkout -b parentBranch
git ...  (do some commits)
git checkout -b childOfParentBranch  (this is while still on branch parentBranch)
git ...  (do some commits)
```

Then I merge, in this exact order (important):

```
git checkout master
git merge childOfParentBranch --no-ff
```

Now how do I do a git log where I can see the name of both branches?

Something along the lines:

```
*
|-Merged parentBranch and childOfParentBranch
```

Or:

```
*
|-Merged parentBranch 
|-Merged childOfParentBranch
```

**EDIT:**
Ive added the commit statements as the lack of them leads to misunderstandings.

Im trying to use "git log" to show me all the branch names merged into master. That includes the name of the parentBranch even if only childOfParentBranch is merged into master. These values are clear if I inpsect with gitk, but i need them with "git log" to do some automation.

Kind regards
Christian

Answer (score 6):

Regarding the edit:

Try `git log --graph --decorate` (perhaps with `--oneline`) and either `--all` (all branches, tags, etc), or name the branches you care about.  Note that branch names (labels) can be deleted or moved at any time, though, so you can't count on the names sticking around.

Until the branch labels *are* moved or deleted, though, you can see which ones are "merged" (point to or below a given commit-ID) with `git branch --contains` and `git branch --merged`.  For instance, given a commit graph that looks like this, with four branch labels as shown denoting commits `G`, `H`, `F`, and `E`:

```
           G   <-- br1
          / \
A--B--C--D---H <-- br2
    \  \    /
     \  F--/   <-- br3
      \
       E       <-- br4
```

you can run, e.g.:

```
git branch --contains br1^   # br1^ identifies commit `D`
```

to see "branches whose tip commits are descendents of the named commit".  Those are `br1` and `br2`.  In other words, starting at `br1`, i.e., `G`, we can walk backwards and reach `D`; and starting at `br2`, i.e., `H`, we can walk backwards and reach `D`.  However, starting at `F` via `br3`, walking backwards does not reach `D`, and starting at `E` via `br4`, walking backwards also does not reach `D`.)

You can also run:

```
git branch --merged br2      # br2 identifies commit H
```

which (as the documentation notes) finds "branches whose tip commits are reachable from the named commit".  This prints `br1`, `br2`, and `br3`.  We start at `H` and walk all backwards paths.  `H` itself is identified by label `br2`, so this prints `br2`.  Then we walk its parents; `H` has three: `D`, `G`, and `F` (one of these is the "first" parent, but the graph shown here does not tell us which one, and for `git branch --merged` git does not care anyway).  Commit `G` is the commit identified by the name `br1`, so this prints `br1`.  Commit `D` is not identified by anything.  Commit `F` is identified by `br3`.  We also check the parents of `D` and `F`: these are `C`, then `B`, then `A` and then there are no more parents.  In this case they all have no labels (but if we were to add one pointing to, say, commit `A`, `git branch --merged` would print that label as well).

(There is also `git branch --no-merged` which, applied to commit `H`, would print `br4` in this case.  It's just the inverse of `--merged`: print branch labels if they point to a commit that is *not* reachable from the given starting point.)

---

Branches don't actually have parent/child relationships (although you can read them into existence if you like—but the point here is that you have to invent them, as it were, from the graph).  Moreover, the command sequence you suggest results in nothing happening.

---

Let me get more specific, because "branch" can refer to two different concepts.  There's the chain of commits formed by the commit directed-graph, and there's the branch *name* that actually provides the "tip" of some branch, such `experiment`, `master`, or `feature`:

```
     C--D--E   <-- experiment
    /
A--B--F--G     <-- master
    \
     H--I      <-- feature
```

The branch that the name `experiment` points to ends with the tip commit `E`.  The branch consists of commits `A` through `E`.  The branch *names* the (single) commit `E`.  But we also talk about "the branch" as being `A` through `E` inclusive.

Meanwhile, the branch that the name `master` points to ends with the tip commit `G`.  The branch consists of `A`, `B`, `F`, and `G`; but the branch just *names* `G`.  As before, "the branch" means two different things, depending on what we want it to mean: the tip, or the line formed by starting at the tip and working backwards.

That said, if you're "on" branch `master` and do two `git checkout -b` commands, that creates two new branch labels.  By default those labels point to the *same* commit as `master`.  So if you start with this:

```
A--B--F--G   <-- HEAD=master
```

and you run:

```
$ git checkout -b br1
Switched to a new branch 'br1'
$ git checkout -b br2
Switched to a new branch 'br2'
```

then you now have:

```
A--B--F--G   <-- master, br1, HEAD=br2
```

All three labels point to the same tip commit (`G`, in this case).  Use `git log --decorate` to see the labels.  (I like to use `git log --oneline --graph --decorate`, with or without `--all` as well, as needed.  Also, I put the `HEAD=` in the above diagrams to tell you which branch you're "on".)

If you then attempt the sequence:

```
$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
$ git merge br1 --no-ff
```

you get a complaint, of sorts:

```
Already up-to-date.
```

Because of this, nothing has happened.

Let's make `br1` into something you *can* merge, by adding an empty commit to it:

```
$ git checkout br1
Switched to branch 'br1'
$ git commit --allow-empty -m 'empty commit'
[br1 add230d] empty commit
```

The graph now looks like this (I'm ignoring `experiment` and `feature` here, and arbitrarily drawing `br1` below `master`):

```
A--B--F--G      <-- master, br2
          \
           J    <-- HEAD=br1
```

(because the newly added commit causes the label `br1` to move to point to it).

Now it's possible to go back to `master` and do a merge:

```
$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
```

This first step just moves the `HEAD` label:

```
A--B--F--G      <-- HEAD=master, br2
          \
           J    <-- br1
```

The next step creates a merge commit:

```
$ git merge --no-ff br1 -m 'merge br1'
Already up-to-date!
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
```

The `merge` adds a new commit with two parents, to whichever branch `HEAD` points to, which is `master`.  The label `master` moves to point to the new commit, as usual.  This makes it a little harder to show where `br2` points, so I'll draw a much longer ASCII arrow:

```
         .--------- br2
         |
         v
A--B--F--G---K  <-- HEAD=master
          \ /
           J    <-- HEAD=br1
```

Note that branch `br2` ends with `G`.  This is the tip of branch `br2`, hence `G` *is* a "tip" commit, even though it's also a parent of merge-commit `K`.

---

There are a bunch of key take-away messages here:

- Branch *names* (which we sometimes call "a branch") provide the **tip** of a branch.
- Branches themselves are formed by the commit graph, and run as long (or short) as we want when we interpret them.  After merging something in you can think of the branch as just the part that "sticks out", i.e., the stuff along the top after `C`:

  ```
       o--o        "branch"
      /    \
  B--C---o--M--o   "main line"
  ```

  or you can think of it as the entire thing all the way back, including commits `B` and `C` here.
- Adding a new commit always results in some branch label moving forward.  Normally `HEAD` names a branch, and that branch label is what moves forward.  (With a "detached HEAD", the `HEAD` file gives a raw commit SHA-1, and `HEAD` itself is modified to contain the new raw commit SHA-1.)
- A merge just creates a new commit that has two (or more) parents, like `M` above.  It is not possible to merge a commit with itself, as a merge commit *must* have at least two distinct parent commits (that's what makes it a merge commit!).

Not shown above, but also a key concept: the "first parent" of the merge is the commit that was "on the branch" before the merge (assuming `HEAD` named a branch), and all other parents are the commits that were "merged in".  Git itself does not really care which way a merge is done—the labels can be changed or erased—but this allows you (the user) to leave a bread-crumb trail, for yourself or anyone else who comes in later to see what was done.

Comment: That was a very thorough answer thank you very much for the effort :). But it shows that my question was not precise enough. I will edit my question right away.

Answer (score 1):

The command `git log --pretty=format:"%h - %an, %ar %s" --graph` can show you the log, where it has been merged

Obviously you can change the format. In the example provided

- `%h`  - abbreviated commit hash
- `%an` - author name
- `%ar` - author date, relative
- `%s`  - subject

Example

```
$ git log --pretty=format:"%h - %an, %ar %s" --graph

*   084648c - XXX, 7 days ago Merge pull request #10 from XXX/oneplugin
|\
| * bb0f3cc - XXX, 7 days ago Switched to using one plugin only
|/
* 91e7ecd - XXX, 7 days ago Removed maven, using gradle instead
* ea6f1ce - XXX, 7 days ago Comments in build.gradle, added descriptions of tasks
* a6b69bb - XXX, 8 days ago Bumped version to 2.6
*   73ae95f - XXX, 8 days ago Merge branch 'master' of XXXXX
|\
| * 3e70f9a - XXX, 8 days ago Update README.md
* | 96913ce - XXX, 8 days ago Working gradle script to upload to OSS
|/
* 91ff7da - XXX, 8 days ago Bumped gradle to 2.6
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
 git log --color --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)%Creset' --abbrev-commit
```